# jquery $_POST callback data is unable to output anything if table is slightly large

Tags: jquery, json

I send some data from main.php to process.php using jquery $_POST. The process.php produce a data table and encode it using json_encode and the returned callback tabular data is showin in main.php page.

page: main.php

```
getData('schedule');

function getData(param){
  $("#result").html("<b>Loading...... Please Wait</b>");
    $.post(url,
     {
       'param':param
     },function(cbdata){
       alert('data received');
      $("#message").html(cbdata.msg).show();
      $("#result").html(cbdata.content).show();
    },"json");
}
```

and the process.php page:

```
if(isset($_POST['param'])){
 extract($_POST);
 if($param=='schedule'){
   //some mysqli operation goes on based on received $param
   //if mysqli operation is successful and a message ($msg = 'Success') is set as success indicator, if fails, a message ($msg='Failed!') is also set.
   //a for loop is conducting to make the fetched rows from database as tabular form in a variable like $content = some data.........here;
   //an str_replace is done to change some words based on some pre-condition
   //finally the data ($content) is ready to sent back to the main.php page
   $arr = array('msg'=>$msg,'content'=>$content);
   echo json_encode($arr);  
 }
}
```

All my $_POST and showing callback data work well until the table get 10 rows. If it get 11 rows (or even if each row data is larger, the row limit can be upto 9 rows), no output is given by the cbdata. Then I put an alert box `alert('Data Received')` to check whether the callbackdata(cbdata) is returing or not. I can see, it is not even returning data, it has been fixed to the message `<b>Loading...... Please Wait</b>` which I set before sending $_POST request.

At first I thought that there may be error in my process.php page or in database. But I found that If I reduce the number of fetched row [for the sent back table] from database by giving some mysqli condition, the `cbdata` is showing. Even If I execute the process.php independently without the $_POST by main.php, the larger table is shown.

So, I cannot find what is making the unavailability of `cbdata` if the table size is slightly larger (I think, a table of 9-10 rows is not a big size table), why the data cannot be processed. I can make you sure that there is no error in code of process.php page, as the same table is showing if executes independently [by executing process.php page alone].

Any idea?

Comment: Check the Network tab of the web console to see the raw response data. Maybe there's an error message that's preventing a correct parse of the JSON.

Comment: Is it your post working properly ?

Comment: Barmar, I don't know how to check Network tab. I-kod, yes `post` working well because if the number of table rows of callback data is less, the table from callback data is showing. If there is error in post, no matter how long the callback table is, data might not be shown.

Comment: Barmar, I checked network tab. Yes in both condition (smaller or larger table): status is 200 in network tab.

Comment: I just have checked returned data using firebug. I can see the callback data is returning. But as soon as I added more rows to my returned callback table this peculiar div is adding at last of table: `<div style="text-align: center;"><div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-left
:auto; z-index:99999"></div></div>` and the callback data is not showing at that moment. If I reduce number of rows from returned callback table, this `div` goes on, and callback data is shown as usual. Do  you think that this `z-index` is creating problem? If yes, then how these divs are adding?